# How to find UIButton by title

Tags: objective-c

I am having a `UIView` that has button in it. The buttons are not in some array.

I would like to look at the whole `UIView` (using `for` loop) and look for a button by its title, and later remove it.

```
- (void)removeButtonByTitle:(NSString*)name
{
    for (buttons in view) {
        // find the button with the name "name" and remove it from the view 
    }
}
```

I couldn't find a way to do that without saving their names/pointers to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally preferable to use the `tag` property for this. Then you can simply find the button with the `viewWithTag:` method and don't have to adjust your code if you decide to change the button title or localize your app.

If you really need to find a button by its title, you could do it like this:

```
NSString *buttonTitle = @"name";
UIButton *buttonWithTitle = nil;
for (UIButton *button in view.subviews) {
    if (![button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) continue;
    if ([[button currentTitle] isEqualToString:buttonTitle]) {
        buttonWithTitle = button;
        break;
    }
}
//do something with the button...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but the tag is not always better. in my case, there is a class that add buttons to a view ,by getting a name as an argument. than later, this class needs to have a method to remove a button by a name, because the names are users that comes and go that i get from a server . so , in that case , its more convenient to use only names. am i wrong ?

Comment: I'd say both solutions aren't really desirable. Ideally, you should keep track of your buttons in a dictionary, if you need to associate them with a username or something like that.

Comment: Agree with @omz. Don't search for the button, keep reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do it like this:

```
for (UIView *v in view.subviews)
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && [[(UIButton *)v currentTitle] isEqualToString:@""])
        //remove
```

But I must say that doesn't sound like a robust solution, your button title could change during localization or it may be different for different states.

Comment: that works but as dmitry said going by title is far from robust. at least give unique tags to the UIButtons (when you create them in ib/code) and try to go by those!

Answer (score 1):

Do that:

```
- (void)removeButtonByTitle:(NSString *)name
{
  for (UIView *tempView in self.subviews)
    {
       if ([tempView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) // make sure it's actually a UIButton
         { 
              UIButton *button = tempView;
              if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:name])  // compare the title
                 {
                    [button removeFromSuperview];
                 }
         }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
-(void)removeButtonWithTitle:(NSString*)titleString {
NSArray *subViews = [self.view subviews];
[subViews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        NSArray *subViewsArray = [(UIView*)obj subviews];
        for (int i=0; i<[subViewsArray count]; i++) {
            id subViewObj = [subViewsArray objectAtIndex:i];
            if([subViewObj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && [[(UIButton*)subViewObj titleLabel].text isEqualToString:titleString]) {
                [subViewObj removeFromSuperview];
                *stop = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}];
}
```